Free action of finite group on a scheme
Let $X$ be an affine scheme over $S$ and let $G$ be a finite group acting freely on $X$.

I saw two definitions in the literature regarding "free action", the first that the map $G\times_S X\to X\times_S X$ mapping $(g,x)$ to $(gx,x)$ is a monomorphism the second that it is a closed embedding. Which one is standard?

I am looking for a citable source giving that the quotient map $X\to X/G$ is finite. I saw it mentioned in some places but could not find a source.



In 1, the two conditions are equivalent (even when $X \to S$ is only assumed separated). Indeed, the map you wrote down is a map of schemes over $X$ (via the second projection), where $G \times_S X \to X$ is finite, hence proper. If $Z$ is the scheme-theoretic image, then $G \times_S X \to Z$ is proper [Tag 01W6], hence a closed immersion if it is a monomorphism [Tag 04XV].

@R.vanDobbendeBruyn do you want to give that as an answer so it can be accepted?  You might mention for the second that $X \rightarrow X/G$ is an $G$-bundle, hence etale-locally of the form $Y \times G \rightarrow Y$, which is finite; and finiteness of morphisms descends under etale maps, thereby answring both questions.

@RaviVakil thanks, but I think mine doesn't fully answer it, so I left a comment. I have the feeling the OP is specifically looking for a citable source, which I'm not sure I can provide.

In the meantime I found Thm 4.16 in https://www.math.ru.nl/~bmoonen/BookAV/Quotients.pdf
It is not from a paper or a book, but might be good enough

@R.vanDobbendeBruyn how is it not citable?
